# While dragging: How to make a view invisible but the drag shadow opaque?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, drag

I have a view that I want to drag and drop onto another view, which works fine. The thing is, that i'd like the view to become invisible while the drag shadow should look solid and appear as the view.

Sadly I can not use `DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE` as I'm not using API 24.

```
drag_same_dc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
            {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(drag_same_dc);
                view.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });
```